# Changing the entries of a list environment

Tags: lists, environments

If I have a new list environment like so:

```
\newenvironment{textblockX}
{ 
    \begin{list}
    {Question}
    {}
}
{
    \end{list}
}
```

How would I refer to an item of the list within the environment? As an example, how could I modify the code above such that every entry is now bold, but the word question stays in normal text? Is this where the `##1` is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't refer to an item in the environment definition because the `\item`s are not part of that definition. They are *only added inside* the environment.
You can use formatting macros like `\bfseries` which don't take arguments but are valid for the whole environment. Then to switch back to normal use `\textnormal{...}` or `\normalfont`. There is also `\normalsize` and `\normalcolor` if you require it.

The environment arguments like `#1` standing for normal macro arguments direct after the `\begin{<env>}` and don't have anything to do with the `\item`s.

```
\newenvironment{textblockX}
{% 
    \bfseries
    \begin{list}%
    {\textnormal{Question}}%
    {}%
}
{%
    \end{list}%
}
```